# How to pass *args or **kwargs itself to the target function of threading.Target?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

A function accepts `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
def b(num, *args, **kwargs):
    print('num', num)
    print('args', args)
    print('kwargs', kwargs)
```

calling it as `b(5, *[1, 2], **{'a': 'b'})` produces the following output:

```
num 5
args (1, 2)
kwargs {'a': 'b'}
```

`threading.Thread(target=b, args=[5, [1, 2], {'a': 'b'}]).start()` gives:

```
num 5
args ([1, 2], {'a': 'b'})
kwargs {}
```

`threading.Thread(target=b, kwargs={'num': 5, '*args': [1, 2], '**kwargs': {'a': 'b'}}).start()` gives:

```
num 5
args ()
kwargs {'**kwargs': {'a': 'b'}, '*args': [1, 2]}
```

What's the correct way to pass *args and **kwargs to this function?

Comment: Your sample call is the same thing as `b(5, 1, 2, a='b')`. Or `b(5, 1, 2, **{'a': 'b'})` or `b(5, a='b', *[1, 2])`. Don't confuse the use of `*` and `**` in the *function signature* with the similar syntax in a *call expression*. The two are related but the function signature does not mean you have to use the `*` and `**` syntax in the call.

Comment: All this isn't really specific to `threading.Thread()`, let alone to [tag:python-multithreading].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
threading.Thread(target=b, args=[5, 1, 2], kwargs={'a': 'b'}).start()
```

gives the expected output. Another option is to use functools. The following code also passes arguments correctly:

```
threading.Thread(target=functools.partial(b, 5, *[1, 2], **{'a': 'b'})).start()
```